# Django with legacy database and foreign keys where id=0

Tags: mysql, django

**EDIT**: This is for Django 2.1

I am working with data that has been migrated from a PHP-based MySQL database to Django. In this PHP database they used foreign keys where the id = 0. So naturally when I try to insert a record that references a foreign key of 0 I get the following:

"The database backend does not accept 0 as a value for AutoField."

Fair enough.

It seems this was done to protect folks from MySQL's use of using 0 to auto generate a primary key:

https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/17713

However there appears to be a way to write a "custom backend" to work around this:

https://www.mail-archive.com/django-users@googlegroups.com/msg187956.html

This seems less than optimal for something that appears to have a session-based solution of setting the following in the MySQL session:

`SET SESSION SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";`

Barring switching the database or other hacks to make this work are there better options to get Django and MySQL to play together with `id=0`?

**EDIT**:

I tried adding the following to my project:

```py
# foo_project/base.py
from django.db.backends.mysql.base import DatabaseWrapper as BaseDatabaseWrapper
from django.db.backends.mysql.features import DatabaseFeatures as BaseDatabaseFeatures

class DatabaseFeatures(BaseDatabaseFeatures):
        allows_auto_pk_0 = True


class DatabaseWrapper(BaseDatabaseWrapper):
    features_class = DatabaseFeatures
```

and in settings.py:

```py
# settings.py
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        # 'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'ENGINE': 'foo_project',
        'NAME': 'foo',
        'USER': 'foouser',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}
```

But that didn't seem to help. I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: i would suggest to replace the `0` with `NULL` when you dump..

Comment: The 0 pointing to actual data. I'm not sure that would help.